# Iterated concatenations and manually applied CDATA in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Thanks to the generous feedback from members here, I've made some significant progress on my XML to XML project.

That said, I'm stuck on two issues in the final version of my project and would like to gain a better understanding of why these issues are occurring.

First I need to create a concatenated element value made up of multiple values. I have this working using the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="estimate/JobParts/JobPart/description">
    <description>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(estimate/description,'_QTY-',estimate/JobParts/JobPart/qtyOrdered,'_',estimate/JobParts/JobPart/itemTemplate)"/>
    </description>
</xsl:template>
```

This finds all the matches for `estimate/JobParts/JobPart/description`, but in all cases uses only the first matching sibling element values when replacing the description value.

Would this be a situation where I would need to use a key to manage the iteration, and if so, how should I go about creating one? Would there be another way of handling this using an apply-template so that the iteration management could be handled automatically, and if so, how would that be constructed?

The other issue I have is that I need to manually add a CDATA designation to an element and cannot add that element to the list in the cdata-section-elements because there is another element with the same name nested deeper in the document structure that does not require the CDATA designation.

Here is the code I am trying to use to manually add the CDATA flag:

```
<xsl:template match="estimate/description">
    <description>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
         &lt;![CDATA[
       </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="estimate/description"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
        ]]&gt;
       </xsl:text>
    </description>
</xsl:template>
```

Interestingly this has no effect whatsoever on the target description element.

If anyone has some ideas why either (or both) of these transforms are not working correctly, I am eager to learn and understand.

Apologies in advance for the barrage of code but here is the original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PODOrderSheet_Main>

    <estimate>
        <customer>LINFNC</customer>
        <newJob>Y</newJob>
        <incrementJobVersion>Y</incrementJobVersion>
        <description><![CDATA[409511]]></description>
        <billPartsTogether>1</billPartsTogether>
        <dateSetup><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></dateSetup>
        <promiseDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></promiseDate>
        <scheduledShipDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></scheduledShipDate>
        <adminStatus>O</adminStatus>
        <shipVia>1</shipVia> 
        <jobType>5020</jobType>
        <poNum><![CDATA[409511]]></poNum>
        <itemTemplate><![CDATA[33503MN_0212]]></itemTemplate>
        <JobParts>
            <JobPart>
                <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                <contactNum/>
                <description><![CDATA[REPLACEMENT OF LIFE INSURANCE OR ANNUITIES MINNESOTA]]></description>
                <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
                <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[3]]></qtyOrdered>
                <shipToContact/>
                <itemTemplate><![CDATA[33503MN_0212]]></itemTemplate>
                <JobNotes>
                    <JobNote>
                        <department>001</department>
                        <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                        <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                    </JobNote>
                </JobNotes>
            </JobPart>
        </JobParts>
    </estimate>

    <estimate>
        <customer>LINFNC</customer>
        <newJob>Y</newJob>
        <incrementJobVersion>Y</incrementJobVersion>
        <description><![CDATA[409511]]></description>
        <billPartsTogether>1</billPartsTogether>
        <dateSetup><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></dateSetup>
        <promiseDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></promiseDate>
        <scheduledShipDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></scheduledShipDate>
        <adminStatus>O</adminStatus>
        <shipVia>1</shipVia> 
        <jobType>5020</jobType>
        <poNum><![CDATA[409511]]></poNum>
        <itemTemplate><![CDATA[AL-FSC-FST068_Z08]]></itemTemplate>
        <JobParts>
            <JobPart>
                <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                <contactNum/>
                <description><![CDATA[AMERICAN LEGACY III C SHARE FACT SHEET ]]></description>
                <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
                <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[1]]></qtyOrdered>
                <shipToContact/>
                <itemTemplate><![CDATA[AL-FSC-FST068_Z08]]></itemTemplate>
                <JobNotes>
                    <JobNote>
                        <department>001</department>
                        <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                        <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                    </JobNote>
                </JobNotes>
            </JobPart>
        </JobParts>
    </estimate>

    <estimate>
        <customer>LINFNC</customer>
        <newJob>Y</newJob>
        <incrementJobVersion>Y</incrementJobVersion>
        <description><![CDATA[409511]]></description>
        <billPartsTogether>1</billPartsTogether>
        <dateSetup><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></dateSetup>
        <promiseDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></promiseDate>
        <scheduledShipDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></scheduledShipDate>
        <adminStatus>O</adminStatus>
        <shipVia>1</shipVia> 
        <jobType>5020</jobType>
        <poNum><![CDATA[409511]]></poNum>
        <itemTemplate><![CDATA[AN06819-AL3C_1012]]></itemTemplate>
        <JobParts>
            <JobPart>
                <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                <contactNum/>
                <description><![CDATA[AMERICAN LEGACY III C SHARE APPLICATION SUPPLEMENT  - MULTI-STATE]]></description>
                <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
                <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[1]]></qtyOrdered>
                <shipToContact/>
                <itemTemplate><![CDATA[AN06819-AL3C_1012]]></itemTemplate>
                <JobNotes>
                    <JobNote>
                        <department>001</department>
                        <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                        <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                    </JobNote>
                </JobNotes>
            </JobPart>
        </JobParts>
    </estimate>

</PODOrderSheet_Main>
```

And here is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE estimate>
<estimate>
    <customer>LINFNC</customer>
    <newJob>Y</newJob>
    <incrementJobVersion>Y</incrementJobVersion>
    <description><![CDATA[409511]]></description>
    <billPartsTogether>1</billPartsTogether>
    <dateSetup><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></dateSetup>
    <promiseDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></promiseDate>
    <scheduledShipDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></scheduledShipDate>
    <adminStatus>O</adminStatus>
    <shipVia>1</shipVia>
    <jobType>5020</jobType>
    <poNum><![CDATA[409511]]></poNum>
    <itemTemplate><![CDATA[33503MN_0212]]></itemTemplate>
    <JobParts>
        <JobPart>
            <jobPart>01</jobPart>
            <contactNum/>
            <description>409511_QTY-3_33503MN_0212</description>
            <priority>1</priority>
            <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
            <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[3]]></qtyOrdered>
            <shipToContact/>
            <itemTemplate><![CDATA[33503MN_0212]]></itemTemplate>
            <JobNotes>
                <JobNote>
                    <department>001</department>
                    <jobPart>01</jobPart>
                    <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                </JobNote>
            </JobNotes>
        </JobPart>
        <JobPart>
            <jobPart>02</jobPart>
            <contactNum/>
            <description>409511_QTY-1_AL-FSC-FST068_Z08</description>
            <priority>1</priority>
            <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
            <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[1]]></qtyOrdered>
            <shipToContact/>
            <itemTemplate><![CDATA[AL-FSC-FST068_Z08]]></itemTemplate>
            <JobNotes>
                <JobNote>
                    <department>001</department>
                    <jobPart>02</jobPart>
                    <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                </JobNote>
            </JobNotes>
        </JobPart>
        <JobPart>
            <jobPart>03</jobPart>
            <contactNum/>
            <description>409511_QTY-1_AN06819-AL3C_1012</description>
            <priority>1</priority>
            <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
            <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[1]]></qtyOrdered>
            <shipToContact/>
            <itemTemplate><![CDATA[AN06819-AL3C_1012]]></itemTemplate>
            <JobNotes>
                <JobNote>
                    <department>001</department>
                    <jobPart>03</jobPart>
                    <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
                </JobNote>
            </JobNotes>
        </JobPart>
    </JobParts>
</estimate>
```

And here is the XSL as it is now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="dateSetup promiseDate scheduledShipDate poNum qtyOrdered itemTemplate note"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/PODOrderSheet_Main">
    <estimate>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/customer"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/newJob"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/incrementJobVersion"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/description"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/billPartsTogether"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/dateSetup"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/promiseDate"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/scheduledShipDate"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/adminStatus"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/shipVia"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/jobType"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/poNum"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="estimate[1]/itemTemplate"/>
        <JobParts>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="estimate/JobParts/JobPart"/>
        </JobParts>
    </estimate>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="estimate/description">
<description>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
     &lt;![CDATA[
   </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="estimate/description"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
    ]]&gt;
   </xsl:text>
</description>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//estimate/JobParts/JobPart/description">
<description>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(//estimate/description,'_QTY-',//JobPart/qtyOrdered,'_',//JobPart/itemTemplate)"/>
</description>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="jobPart">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:number count="JobPart" level="any" format="01"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Many thanks...

Comment: Please edit your post to provide a more descriptive title actually related to the problem you're having.

Comment: Also, since you cannot assume that people have read your previous questions, please include a complete sample of your input and the according expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your stylesheet:

- You are including the `estimate/description` element using `xsl:copy-of`. Because of that you will simply get a *copy* of the element, and the template that matches `estimate/description` will never be applied to transform it.
- The location paths in `match` and `select` attributes can be either *absolute* or *relative* to the context node. Absolute location paths are often a sign of poor stylesheet design, and make it very difficult to pick out one of several nodes with a matching path. As you have discovered, a set of nodes is converted to a string by taking the string value of the first node in the set. Rather than messing about with picking a single node from the set using `position()` somehow, it is best to use relative localtion paths.
- It seems you are unclear about the use of *CDATA*, *PCDATA* and *entities*. The are simply different ways of representing special characters in the text nodes of XML, and the *meaning* of, say `<![CDATA[use <> in Perl for reading]]>` and `use &lt;&gt; in Perl for reading` is *identical*. Since you just have two alternative ways of representing the same text string, it is unlikely that you would specifically want one or the other, but it is possible that you have a finicky piece of software that demands its XML data be "just so".

This transform does what you need. I have changed the initial `xsl:copy` list to simply `xsl:apply-templates` to all children of the first `estimate` element that have no child elements themselves. This way the `estimate/description` template comes into effect and the `CDATA` tag is applied. The `JobPart/description` template pulls the three values required for the compound description string into three `XSL` variables to make things neater.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output cdata-section-elements="dateSetup promiseDate scheduledShipDate poNum itemTemplate qtyOrdered note"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/PODOrderSheet_Main">
        <estimate>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="estimate[1]/*[not(*)]"/>
            <JobParts>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="estimate/JobParts/JobPart"/>
            </JobParts>
        </estimate>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="estimate/description">
        <description>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
        </description>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="JobPart/description">
        <xsl:variable name="estimate-description" select="ancestor::estimate/description"/>
        <xsl:variable name="qty-ordered" select="parent::JobPart/qtyOrdered"/>
        <xsl:variable name="item-template" select="parent::JobPart/itemTemplate"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($estimate-description, '_QTY-', $qty-ordered, '_', $item-template)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="jobPart">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:number count="JobPart" level="any" format="01"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<estimate>
   <customer>LINFNC</customer>
   <newJob>Y</newJob>
   <incrementJobVersion>Y</incrementJobVersion>
   <description><![CDATA[409511]]></description>
   <billPartsTogether>1</billPartsTogether>
   <dateSetup><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></dateSetup>
   <promiseDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></promiseDate>
   <scheduledShipDate><![CDATA[4/24/2013]]></scheduledShipDate>
   <adminStatus>O</adminStatus>
   <shipVia>1</shipVia>
   <jobType>5020</jobType>
   <poNum><![CDATA[409511]]></poNum>
   <itemTemplate><![CDATA[33503MN_0212]]></itemTemplate>
   <JobParts>
      <JobPart>
         <jobPart>01</jobPart>
         <contactNum/>
         <description>409511_QTY-3_33503MN_0212</description>
         <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
         <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[3]]></qtyOrdered>
         <shipToContact/>
         <itemTemplate><![CDATA[33503MN_0212]]></itemTemplate>
         <JobNotes>
            <JobNote>
               <department>001</department>
               <jobPart>01</jobPart>
               <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
            </JobNote>
         </JobNotes>
      </JobPart>
      <JobPart>
         <jobPart>02</jobPart>
         <contactNum/>
         <description>409511_QTY-1_AL-FSC-FST068_Z08</description>
         <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
         <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[1]]></qtyOrdered>
         <shipToContact/>
         <itemTemplate><![CDATA[AL-FSC-FST068_Z08]]></itemTemplate>
         <JobNotes>
            <JobNote>
               <department>001</department>
               <jobPart>02</jobPart>
               <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
            </JobNote>
         </JobNotes>
      </JobPart>
      <JobPart>
         <jobPart>03</jobPart>
         <contactNum/>
         <description>409511_QTY-1_AN06819-AL3C_1012</description>
         <productionStatus>O</productionStatus>
         <qtyOrdered><![CDATA[1]]></qtyOrdered>
         <shipToContact/>
         <itemTemplate><![CDATA[AN06819-AL3C_1012]]></itemTemplate>
         <JobNotes>
            <JobNote>
               <department>001</department>
               <jobPart>03</jobPart>
               <note><![CDATA[Rush Order]]></note>
            </JobNote>
         </JobNotes>
      </JobPart>
   </JobParts>
</estimate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response, feedback and solution. This works great. FYI, this is being used in an Enfocus Switch workflow solution that dynamically passes an XML input to an XSLT transform element that delivers the transformed file. So I fully understand your comments, you are saying that no templates can be applied to copied elements within the same stylesheet? Interestingly, I had been using relative paths throughout but made them absolute for clarity when posting the XSLT. The client I am working with dictated that I needed to match their output exactly, hence the CDATA step.

Comment: I also wanted to ask about the concat function. I note you created variables with relative paths to the ancestor and parent elements and used those variables versus using the paths in the concat function directly. Is that considered best practice for building concatenated replacement value strings? Thanks again for the tips.

Comment: It sounds like your client needs educating. I'm afraid that is too often the case. The code will work just the same if you put the appropriate `select` statements in the corresponding parameters of `concat()`, but I think it's clearer that way. It isn't best practice particularly, except that code should be as clear and descriptive as possible in any software.

Comment: It's not so much that *"no templates can be applied to copied elements"*, it's just that there are several ways to send data to the output of a transform. `xsl:copy` makes a direct copy, or you can use `xsl:element`, `xsl:value-of` etc. to build something different. `xsl:apply-templates` allows you to write a template that matches the node and processes it in a particular way.

Answer (score 1):

> The other issue I have is that I need to manually add a CDATA designation to an element and cannot add that element to the list in the cdata-section-elements because there is another element with the same name nested deeper in the document structure that does not require the CDATA designation.

It makes no difference to an XML parser whether a particular bit of character data is represented using a CDATA section or not, `<foo>something</foo>` is exactly the same as `<foo><![CDATA[something]]></foo>`.  Indeed, adding the cdata wrapper manually using disable-output-escaping will *not* necessarily produce the correct thing, because the serializer doesn't realise the text it's outputting is in a CDATA and will escape it with entities anyway: if you have a `description` element like

```
<description><![CDATA[409 < 511]]></description>
```

then trying to copy this to the output with d-o-e CDATA markers will produce

```
<description><![CDATA[409 &lt; 511]]></description>
```

You would be better off not bothering with the CDATA at all and just let the serializer do entity escapes in the normal way

```
<description>409 &lt; 511</description>
```

(which is equivalent to the original element).